# max date for individual customer id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need the max date for an individual customer.  There is 1 customer more than 1 time in a table with unique customer id, meaning customers are repeating in the table. I want their latest date.

This is the query

```
SELECT  sum(receipt_table.installment_amount) total_installment,
        receipt_table.customer_id, 
        customer_info.name,
        customer_info.mobile,
        customer_info.plot_number,
        customer_info.amount, 
        max(receipt_table.date_time) last_date 
FROM    receipt_table,customer_info 
WHERE   customer_info.installment_type = 'monthly-12'
AND     customer_info.customer_id = receipt_table.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING  (customer_info.amount - sum(receipt_table.installment_amount) != 0)
```

Table structure like that(receipt_table)

```
customer_id     receipt_id  installment_amount  date_time       
 41                115         1000              2014-07-27
 42                 116        1000              2014-07-27
 41                 117        1000              2014-07-30
 42                 118        1000              2014-07-30
```

I am getting  max date is 2014-07-27 for individual customer

Comment: I can see that you have `Max(date_time)` in your query already... is this not giving you the correct results?  What results are you *currently* getting, and what results are you *expecting*?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question (perhaps the most frequently asked question), so it'll probably get closed as a duplicate in a couple of minutes. If it doesn't... and if you feel like it, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: yes, siyual I am not getting result like I want,I want max date according to each customer

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this instead of group by id group by name:
SELECT  sum(receipt_table.installment_amount) total_installment,receipt_table.  
customer_info.name, max(receipt_table.date_time)last_date FROM 
receipt_table,customer_info where customer_info.installment_type='monthly-12'and      
customer_info.customer_id=receipt_table.customer_id GROUP BY customer_name
```

Comment: Names usually aren't distinct (ie, `'John Smith'`), so the results probably are going to be way off.  If they _were_ unique, there'd be no difference from using the id (well, except it'd likely be slower, due to `name` not being the join column)